# Listing public datasets via API

Tags: google-bigquery

Is there a way to include public datasets that are visible under a project in BQ cloud console (i.e. publicdata:samples) in datasets.list() / projects.list() ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes - just use project "**publicdata**" and the datasetId of "**samples**" in your API calls.

```
import httplib2
from apiclient import errors
service = build('bigquery', 'v2')

# Auth (however your app does this)

tables = service.tables()
table_list = tables.list(projectId='publicdata',
                         datasetId='samples').execute()
```

From the API Console:

```
GET https://www.googleapis.com/bigquery/v2/projects/publicdata/datasets/samples/tables


{
 "kind": "bigquery#tableList",
 "etag": "\"asdasdsadsadsad\"",
 "tables": [
  {

   "kind": "bigquery#table",
   "id": "publicdata:samples.github_nested",
   "tableReference": {
    "projectId": "publicdata",
    "datasetId": "samples",
    "tableId": "github_nested"
   },
   "type": "TABLE"
  },
  {

   "kind": "bigquery#table",
   "id": "publicdata:samples.github_timeline",
   "tableReference": {
    "projectId": "publicdata",
    "datasetId": "samples",
    "tableId": "github_timeline"
   },
   "type": "TABLE"
  },
  {

   "kind": "bigquery#table",
   "id": "publicdata:samples.gsod",
   "tableReference": {
    "projectId": "publicdata",
    "datasetId": "samples",
    "tableId": "gsod"
   },
   "type": "TABLE"
  },
  {

   "kind": "bigquery#table",
   "id": "publicdata:samples.natality",
   "tableReference": {
    "projectId": "publicdata",
    "datasetId": "samples",
    "tableId": "natality"
   },
   "type": "TABLE"
  },
  {

   "kind": "bigquery#table",
   "id": "publicdata:samples.shakespeare",
   "tableReference": {
    "projectId": "publicdata",
    "datasetId": "samples",
    "tableId": "shakespeare"
   },
   "type": "TABLE"
  },
  {

   "kind": "bigquery#table",
   "id": "publicdata:samples.trigrams",
   "tableReference": {
    "projectId": "publicdata",
    "datasetId": "samples",
    "tableId": "trigrams"
   },
   "type": "TABLE"
  },
  {

   "kind": "bigquery#table",
   "id": "publicdata:samples.wikipedia",
   "tableReference": {
    "projectId": "publicdata",
    "datasetId": "samples",
    "tableId": "wikipedia"
   },
   "type": "TABLE"
  }
 ],
 "totalItems": 7
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but here table.list() is being called with the project and dataset. Is it somehow possible for the project "public" to be included when calling projects.list() ?

Comment: No - it acts just like any other user's project. In this case, the 'publicdata' project belongs to the BigQuery team. It's very similar to a project being owned by some other user, but having the dataset (in this case, 'samples'), being available publicly to any BigQuery user to access for querying.